# Sitecore Analytics: Trigger profiles and events from webservice

Tags: sitecore

I have a problem with `Sitecore.Analytics`

From my xslt, I do an ajax call to a webservice using jQuery.

In my webservice I need to register/save some `Sitecore.Analytics` data. 
The problem is that I can't use `Sitecore.Analytics.AnalyticsTracker.Current`.

So how do I do `TriggerProfile` and `TriggerEvent`?
I wonder if `Sitecore.Analytics.AnalyticsManager` could be to any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recently encountered a similar scenario in having to track an analytics event within a webservice. As you noted, the problem is that `AnalyticsTracker.Current` is null within the context of a webservice.

The reason for this is that `AnalytisTracker.Current` is populated during the `trackAnalytics` pipeline, which in turn is invoked during the `renderLayout` pipeline, which is only invoked if the context item is not null and the context item has presentation settings defined.

With that said, there is a workaround :)

You can start the `AnalyticsTracker` manually like so:

```
if (!AnalyticsTracker.IsActive)
{
    AnalyticsTracker.StartTracking();
}
```

You can then retrieve an `AnalyticsTracker` instance like so:

```
AnalyticsTracker tracker = AnalyticsTracker.Current;
if (tracker == null)
    return;
```

And finally, you can create and trigger your event, profile, etc... The example below triggers a `PageEvent`. Note: there is a special consideration to be made for a `PageEvent` (and most likely other events) in order to get the `Timestamp` property populated. See the comments in the code below.

```
if (!AnalyticsTracker.IsActive)
{
    AnalyticsTracker.StartTracking();
}

AnalyticsTracker tracker = AnalyticsTracker.Current;
if (tracker == null)
    return;

string data = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer != null
                        ? HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery
                        : string.Empty;

//Need to set a context item in order for the AnalyticsPageEvent.Timestamp property to 
//be set. As a hack, just set the context item to a known item before declaring the event, 
//then set the context item to null afterwards.
Sitecore.Context.Item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore");

AnalyticsPageEvent pageEvent = new AnalyticsPageEvent();
pageEvent.Name = "Download Registration Form Submitted";
pageEvent.Key = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
pageEvent.Text = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
pageEvent.Data = data;

//Set the AnalyticsPageEvent.Item property to null and the context item to null.
//This way the PageEvent isn't tied to the item you specified as the context item.
pageEvent.Item = null; 
Sitecore.Context.Item = null;

tracker.CurrentPage.TriggerEvent(pageEvent);
tracker.Submit();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I just like to add an extra comment to share my experience. In case you have a POST RESTful service call in which you implement the method to register Page Events,  **make sure to use Simple REST client extension of Chrome instead of Fiddler for sending the POST request** . I ran into a situation where I was using Fiddler to call POST RESTful service, the code was executing fine, but I did not see any entry in the Page Events Table (Problem I think could have been associated to the browser session maybe).

For DMS 2.0, I followed similar article on StackOverflow and wrote the following to register the event.

```
void TriggerPageEvent(string eventName)
{

  if (!Tracker.IsActive)
                {
                    Tracker.StartTracking();
                }

                Sitecore.Data.Database db = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("web");
                Sitecore.Context.Item = db.GetItem("/sitecore");

                PageEventData pageEventData = new PageEventData(eventName);
                pageEventData.Text = "Value is here";
                pageEventData.DataKey = String.Empty;
                pageEventData.Data = " Data is here";
                pageEventData.ItemId = new Guid(Cms.Context.Item.ID.ToString());
                Tracker.CurrentPage.Register(pageEventData);
                Tracker.Submit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to register page event/goal and you use your custom handler to get data from ajax/jquery request, please be sure if your location for the handler an appropriate for the analytic. It means, if your handler is located, for example in /mylocation/myhandlers/myhandler.ashx you need to implement next, add this string to your config file:

```
<site name="your_name" virtualFolder="/mylocation/myhandlers" physicalFolder="/mylocation/myhandlers" enableAnalytics="true" domain="sitecore" database="master" patch:before="site[@name='website']" />
```

It should help. As you can see, in this case, your analytic is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to include the attribute/value `[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]` to your `WebMethod`, and this will work correctly.