# Sitecore Analytics: Trigger Event from REST service (Sitecore 6.5)

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms

I am fairly new to Sitecore Analytics and I ran into situation where I want to save some Analytics data once a REST Service is called.

I am using Fiddler to call POST REST Service. Within REST Service (I have followed a similar article [Sitecore Analytics: Trigger profiles and events from webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118010/sitecore-analytics-trigger-profiles-and-events-from-webservice)), I wrote the following code. I am passing the correct dummy eventName `MLN360_BLDG_CLK_EN`, which I have create under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Page Events/`

```
void TriggerPageEvent(string eventName)
{
  if (!Tracker.IsActive)
  {
    Tracker.StartTracking();
  }

  Sitecore.Data.Database db = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("web");
  Sitecore.Context.Item  = db.GetItem("/sitecore");

  PageEventData pageEventData = new PageEventData(eventName);
  pageEventData.Text = "Value is here";
  pageEventData.DataKey = String.Empty;
  pageEventData.Data = " Data is here";
  pageEventData.ItemId = new Guid(Sitecore.Context.Item.ID.ToString());
  Tracker.CurrentPage.Register(pageEventData);                
  Tracker.Submit();
}
```

However, I don't seen any records in `PageEvents` table at all. If I use this code and paste it in a Item(.aspx page) that has Presentation layout assigned and call this Item (.aspx page) using web browser, the record is added to the database

How can I register event using webservice and also, how can I test it using client like Fiddler?

Thank you

Comment: Have you deployed the PageEvent from within Sitecore? In the content editor, click the 'Review' tab, then click the 'Deploy' button in the 'Workflow' chunk. Though if you hadn't already done this, I would suspect an exception would be thrown when you try to register the event in the analytics tracker.

Comment: @AdamWeber: Yes, I have deployed the Page Events already. I see my events in PageEventDefinitions Table as well but not in PageEvents Table.

Comment: Interesting. I tried your code in my local environment and wasn't able to reproduce the issue, i.e. the page event was being registered as expected in the PageEvents table. The only modifications I made to the code were to remove setting the Sitecore.Context.Item - you don't need to do that with DMS. Have you checked the Analytics.TrackerChanges.FlushInterval setting in Sitecore.Analytics.config? Perhaps the interval is set to some large number and it's just taking a long time for the tracker data to be written to the database?

Comment: @AdamWeber: Strangely enough, if I paste this code in the page (which has layout) and call through web browser, the events are getting registered. However, if I use Fiddler and send a GET request for the same URL, the code gets executed, but page events doesn't get registered. I know for certain that Fiddler doesn't send some information during the request due to which the Tracker has no information what to track and so it doesn't complain and it doesn't register the page events. How can I use Fiddler like client to send request which gets tracked and we can see entry in the PageEvents Table.

Comment: @AdamWeber: Finally!! The issue was with using Fiddler, I used the Simple REST client extension of google instead to make a request and I could see the Page Events in the database. Thank you Adam.

Comment: Glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with using the Fiddler, as they say "Half knowledge is extremely dangerous". I instead switched to Simple REST client extension of Chrome to make the requests and I could see the events in the Page Events Table.