# Tracking a Page Event from ASHX Handler

Tags: sitecore, ashx, sitecore8, sitecore8.1, sitecore-analytics

Im currently trying to track a PageEvent within a ASHX Handler. My code basically looks like this:

```
public class GetProductPdf : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!Tracker.IsActive)
        { 
            Tracker.Initialize();
            Tracker.StartTracking();
        }

        //Track PageEvent here...
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The Tracker is always inactive and Tracker.Current == null. On method call "Tracker.StartTracking();" the following Exception is thrown:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Tracker.Current is not initialized]
Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartAnalytics.StartTracking.Process(PipelineArgs args) +317
(Object , Object[] ) +83
Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +445
 Project.Web.Handler.PdfCreation.GetProductPdf.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in d:\Project\Website\Handler\PdfCreation\GetProductPdf.ashx.cs:69
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +913
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165
```

I tried all possible solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118010/sitecore-analytics-trigger-profiles-and-events-from-webservice).

When doing the same in a mvc controller the Tracker is active and Tracker.Current != null.

Does anyone has an idea, what could cause this or are there any other suggestions for a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How have you registered your handler? If you do it in the same way the `sitecore_media_handler` is registered, then you will have a valid Sitecore context.

Comment: I think it's a questions of timing and the handler is firing too soon. There is a pipeline to initialize the tracker so you shouldn't need to do it. If your code is called after this then Tracker should work fine. However if you do need to call initialize I'm pretty sure it relies on session being available, so you could try adding IRequiresSessionState to your handler.

Answer (score 2):

I am not certain that your `Ashx Handler` can be executed within the necessary Sitecore Context so that `Tacker.Current` will not be valid nor can be started via `Tracker.StartTracking()`. Someone might be able to confirm but I have another solution you can try which works for me.

As nice as it would be for the `Ashx Handler` to register the `Event` for you, instead you can fire a JavaScript function on the link to the file. So that when the link is clicked the JavaScript makes a web request to a `MVC Controller` and the controller registers the event for you.

I have implemented this myself using `WebApi Controllers`. `Data Attributes` were on the `a tag`, JavaScript posted those attributes to the controller, the controller used those attributes to determine which `Event` to register and the `description` to use on the Event.

```cs
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" data-goalid="{08030449-A811-428B-95F0-59FCD42B8DEB}" data-goaldescription="Product 0112 brochure">
```

```cs
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public JsonResult RegisterGoal(string goalId, string goalDescription)
{
    Item eventItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(goalId);
    var goal = new PageEventItem(eventItem);

    var eventData = Tracker.Current.PreviousPage.Register(goal);
    eventData.Data = goal["Description"] + " " + goalDescription;
    Tracker.Current.Interaction.AcceptModifications();

    return Json(new PageEventRequestResult()
    {
        Success = true,
        Message = "Successfully registered goal",
    });
}
```

It works really well. The only downside is having to add it to the various links that lead to the files you want to track.

I wrote a blog about [tracking various interactions on a site and registering Sitecore Events / Goals](http://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2015/12/08/how-to-extend-sitecore-experience-database/) you might want to look at, scroll down to the 'Storing custom data in xDB' section.

Comment: It all depends on how you register the handler. Media requests are served by a handler, that has a valid Sitecore context. You just have to register it with Sitecore and not in the standard .net way.

Comment: That's good to know, it'll be interesting to see if OP comes back with it working once registered with Sitecore

Comment: Thanks for your answeres.
I considered the first solution myself, but since there will be requests from external sources, we also want to track, this is not an option.

The handler actually was registered the sitecore way. I also saw solutions where this was done and worked, but not for me.

Apparently, after debugging for some hours and not making any significant changes, the Tracker started working for no reason...
I have no idea, why it is working right now or why it didn't work before, but now it is.

Still thanks for your help and time.